# how can I improve my code for this task

Tags: java

I am newbie to object orientated programming and trying to construct something which resembles a basic vote counter which should take an *int* parameter that represents a choice of two candidates and print the election results to the terminal window. albeit *(the votes attributable to each candidate and the total votes cast)*

The method I am looking for should also return a string that gives information on the success or failure of casting the vote.”your vote has been cast” “invalid choice, no vote cast"

I have created a class and the constructors and also implemented some basic get methods.

I am wondering how I should go about achieving this objective albeit through a conditional statement or using some sort of advanced method.

any help in terms of the syntax or wider approach would be appreciated.

```
public class VoteCounter {
    private String candidate1;
    private String candidate2;
    private int candidate1Votes;
    private int candidate2Votes;
    private boolean completed;

    public VoteCounter(String candidate1, String candidate2) {
        this.candidate1 = candidate1;
        this.candidate2 = candidate2;
        this.candidate1Votes = 0;
        this.candidate2Votes = 0;
        this.completed = false;
    }

    public VoteCounter() {
        this("CANDIDATE 1", "CANDIDATE 2");
     }


     public String getCandidate1 () {
         return this.candidate1; 
     }


     public String getCandidate2 () {
         return this.candidate2; 
     }


     public Boolean getCompleted () {
         return this.completed; 
     }


     public void setCompleted (boolean completed) {
         this.completed = completed;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match, since you don't want to improve a method, you want the code for your task. Also please remove the comment `//or could implement as:` because `this("CANDIDATE 1", "CANDIDATE 2");` is already a clean and nice implementation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this Kind of questions should be asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: my apologies. brand new to the site.

Comment: Welcome syntax, I'm sorry for such a rude welcome. As Tom said about your constructor, it's the preferred approach, but to explain why: You want to stay as war away from repeating the same code as possible, if you have any code that repeats itself, you cut it, make a method and paste it there and just call that method, if you decide to update that code you only need to do it once, instead of everywhere where you use it. In short, easier maintainability and overview.

Comment: appreciate the steering. only a month into my software degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private String vote(int choice)
{
  if(choice == 1)
  {
    candidate1Votes++;
  }
  else if(choice == 2)
  {
    candidate2Votes++;
  }
  else
  {
    return "invalid choice, no vote cast";
  }
  return "your vote has been cast";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that in more general manner, avoiding code duplication and allowing to change number of candidates easily.
So let's make a class Vote similar to your VoteCounter but only for one candidate, with following fields:

```
private String candidate;  // init this in constructor
private int candidateVotes;  // initially 0, so no need to init
```

and with vote() method like in other answer but also without a candiadate, so:

```
public void vote() {
  candidateVotes++;
}
```

Then you can make class VoteCounter which will take any number of candidates and will keep them in Array or Map.

```
Map<Integer, Vote> votes = new HashMap<>();
```

then you're creating vote method with choice:

```
public void vote(int choice) {
    votes.get(choice).vote();
}
```

Then all is left is to iterate through your votes map and find the one with biggest number of votes.